# Windows form Background image set as stretch but background color is appearing in upper side

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-core

[image]

I set background image as stretch in windows form application. But background color is appearing on top position of windows form.
I already set the windows form

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

But nothing is working.

This is my background image:
[image]

Comment: What format does the image have, jpg or png?

Comment: Can you upload your background image, I have no problem with my test.

Comment: @TaW jpg format

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT yes i have uploaded the background image.

Comment: What do we see in the upper image? What controls are the three areas? Do they have rounded corners??